# Run Code at Editor Startup

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to download few libraries at Editor startup and and set few environment variables. To do this I'm following https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RunningEditorCodeOnLaunch.html

My problem is that the code marked with `[InitializeOnLoad]` doesn't run if the project doesn't compile and the project doesn't compile because of the missing libraries which I'm trying to download with `[InitializeOnLoad]` code.

I would like to avoid running external scripts outside every time before opening Unity Editor as most likely some developer will forget do this extra step and weird errors may appear.

Do you know any workaround to run some code when opening the Editor even if other parts of the project don't compile?

Comment: *"marked with [InitializeOnLoad] doesn't run if the project doesn't compile"* That doesn't really make sense. Can you explain why it doesn't compile?

Comment: @Programmer because I don't have the external libraries which I'm trying to download with the code in `[InitializeOnLoad]` class. The code inside my `[InitializeOnLoad]` class doesn't require the libraries, only the game code needs them